# Update Edit Field with property set by FileBrowse dialog

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

I have an Edit field that begin's empty. The user uses a button that launches the FileBrowse dialog and allows them to choose a file. This is all working, the file is stored into a property and the functionality is as intended.

However, the Edit Field is not being updated once the user chooses the file. Going forward then back a dialog shows the property in the field, but I can't ask the user to do this. I have read that this is an MSI limitation and was wondering if there are any ways around it.

Essentially I need to "refresh" the dialog, or at least the edit field control after the user chooses their file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation from Windows Installer. The only solution to overcome this from an MSI package is to use the [twin dialog method.](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-combobox-listbox.html#combolist-twin-dialog)

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but how would I open the twin dialog in InstallShield? A .dll is handling the file browse so it isn't a dialog that I can change what the "next" button does.

Comment: You need access to its dialog editor, otherwise you cannot implement this method. Also, InstallShield should provide a standard BrowseDlg in the list of predefined dialogs, which you can edit.

Comment: It does provide a "InstallChangeFolder" but the FileBrowse.dll doesn't use this, it opens up a normal windows file browse dialog, not one wrapped inside an installshield dialog. Any way around?

Comment: Just add an additional NewDialog (for the twin dialog) control event after the one that lauches the FileBrowse dialog.

Comment: @MichaelUrman I don't know why I didn't think of this... anyhow, implemented and it works perfectly, you wouldn't even know the dialog changes. Thanks :)

Comment: However once the duplicate dialog is created, and the user browses for a different file again, how does the Edit Field update again? Does the duplicate dialog also need to call NewDialog event to open the original dialog? (which causes wait cursor in my case and I have to kill msiexec.exe)?